# Size of <blockquote>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

```
{%  for post in post_list %}
        <div class="row"> 
               <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">  
                   <div class="homepost">
                        <blockquote>                                                   
                            <a class="h3" href="{%  url 'posts:detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                            <footer>By {{ post.user }}</footer>
                        </blockquote>
                        <p>{{ post.content|lower|truncatechars:"15" }}</p>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item-text">{{ post.likes }} people like this</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item-text">{{ post.comments.count }} Comments </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
{% endfor%}
```

Here is my code, the thing is my blockquote size is different than my actual article size.

Like this,

[image]

The thing is there is a white space in the left upper corner of every post block, and that came after I used blockquote. Like in first post,

Test post 
- By luvpreet

there is a white rectangle to its left, why is that thing happening?

What is its solution ?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking.  Can you update your question to explain more clearly how what you are seeing is different from what you expect/want to see?

Comment: see now, anything?

Answer (score 0):

The light gray box flush to the left is how bootstrap styles `<blockquote>`.

See [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-blockquotes).

If you don't like that style you have two choices:

1. Override the native bootstrap style with your own CSS.
2. Don't use the `blockquote` tag

For me you are not really using the blockquote tag as it is [semantically intended](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-blockquote-element.html).

> The blockquote element represents a section that is quoted from
>   another source.

Maybe something like this:

```
<div>                                                   
        <h3><a class="h3" href="{%  url 'posts:detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
        <p>By {{ post.user }}</footer></p>
</div>
```